# How do I get seconds from Epoch Time in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, time, type-conversion, epoch

I have a data that are being recorded and the time is used in epoch. I want to draw a figure where the x axis from zero to the time that the recorder stopped recording in seconds.

From my search I found that the output for decoding is a string that represent a date for example 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 for all the data. how can I get different data using variable double or float array with the seconds only.

The method I used is :

```
output = datastr(datenum('1970','yyyy') + **timeinepoch** / 86400)
```

The problem is that all numbers give me the same output ?? and I want my data to be in array of seconds

here is a sample of my data **timeinepoch**

```
1.431344867477355
1.431344857732564
1.431344856832909
```

Here is the full data set:

```
1.43134485683291    1.43134485693360    1.43134485703513    1.43134485713490    1.43134485723280    1.43134485733824    1.43134485743525    1.43134485753449    1.43134485763714    1.43134485773256    1.43134485783254    1.43134485793235    1.43134485803481    1.43134485813486    1.43134485823259    1.43134485835510    1.43134485845240    1.43134485855250    1.43134485863259    1.43134485875249    1.43134485901518    1.43134485905522    1.43134485915475    1.43134485925273    1.43134485935277    1.43134485961262    1.43134485965299    1.43134485975277    1.43134486003268    1.43134486005289    1.43134486015272    1.43134486025242    1.43134486035263    1.43134486045254    1.43134486055257    1.43134486065708    1.43134486075720    1.43134486085483    1.43134486095482    1.43134486105451    1.43134486115239    1.43134486125257    1.43134486135232    1.43134486145473    1.43134486156251    1.43134486166082    1.43134486175443    1.43134486185417    1.43134486195630    1.43134486205711    1.43134486215445    1.43134486225478    1.43134486235478    1.43134486245782    1.43134486255472    1.43134486265428    1.43134486275417    1.43134486285418    1.43134486295735    1.43134486305517    1.43134486315859    1.43134486325497    1.43134486349503    1.43134486371503    1.43134486375591    1.43134486385563    1.43134486397315    1.43134486407340    1.43134486417604    1.43134486427350    1.43134486437951    1.43134486455631    1.43134486457633    1.43134486467658    1.43134486477340    1.43134486497348    1.43134486507374    1.43134486517375    1.43134486527400    1.43134486537473    1.43134486547398    1.43134486557386    1.43134486567653    1.43134486577353    1.43134486587349    1.43134486597379    1.43134486607428    1.43134486617383    1.43134486628100    1.43134486637383    1.43134486647394    1.43134486657705    1.43134486680117    1.43134486687743    1.43134486697392    1.43134486707380    1.43134486717390    1.43134486727392    1.43134486737474    1.43134486747735    1.43134486757405    1.43134486767487    1.43134486777720    1.43134486787406    1.43134486797408    1.43134486807391    1.43134486819397    1.43134486829631    1.43134486840328    1.43134486849407    1.43134486859779    1.43134486869804    1.43134486879936    1.43134486889866    1.43134486899881    1.43134486909768    1.43134486919874    1.43134486929967    1.43134486940763    1.43134486950093    1.43134486959617    1.43134486981928    1.43134486989792    1.43134486999540    1.43134487009956    1.43134487039972    1.43134487042361    1.43134487049624    1.43134487060021    1.43134487070231    1.43134487079760    1.43134487089896    1.43134487099949    1.43134487110444    1.43134487119963    1.43134487129876    1.43134487140495    1.43134487150104    1.43134487160027    1.43134487170040    1.43134487180006    1.43134487210409    1.43134487212087    1.43134487220746    1.43134487230004    1.43134487241783    1.43134487252381    1.43134487262215    1.43134487272497    1.43134487282255    1.43134487292190    1.43134487302461    1.43134487326157    1.43134487332114    1.43134487355694    1.43134487357972    1.43134487361634    1.43134487371551    1.43134487399863    1.43134487401961    1.43134487411639    1.43134487421621    1.43134487439989    1.43134487441579    1.43134487451955    1.43134487461955    1.43134487471571    1.43134487481559    1.43134487491635    1.43134487501848    1.43134487511487    1.43134487521501    1.43134487531496    1.43134487541704    1.43134487552202    1.43134487561431    1.43134487571751    1.43134487581402    1.43134487591894    1.43134487602015    1.43134487613423    1.43134487621410    1.43134487631731    1.43134487641786    1.43134487659714    1.43134487673393    1.43134487681434    1.43134487701392    1.43134487703518    1.43134487713382    1.43134487723364    1.43134487733365    1.43134487743375    1.43134487759371    1.43134487773641    1.43134487785339    1.43134487793634    1.43134487803643    1.43134487813655    1.43134487823342    1.43134487849361    1.43134487851616    1.43134487853355    1.43134487863344    1.43134487873596    1.43134487883580    1.43134487893613    1.43134487919309    1.43134487923546    1.43134487933296    1.43134487943276    1.43134487953302    1.43134487963559    1.43134487973314    1.43134487983300    1.43134487993340    1.43134488003292    1.43134488013271    1.43134488023378    1.43134488033261    1.43134488043273    1.43134488053349    1.43134488063484    1.43134488073241    1.43134488083240    1.43134488093250    1.43134488103234    1.43134488113241    1.43134488123247    1.43134488133228    1.43134488145383    1.43134488153225    1.43134488163231    1.43134488173227    1.43134488185237    1.43134488195241    1.43134488205459    1.43134488229584    1.43134488235311    1.43134488245397    1.43134488255799    1.43134488265537    1.43134488275233    1.43134488285382    1.43134488295301    1.43134488305791    1.43134488315417    1.43134488325425    1.43134488335773    1.43134488345386    1.43134488355616    1.43134488365414    1.43134488375686    1.43134488385423    1.43134488395399    1.43134488405443    1.43134488415406    1.43134488425404    1.43134488435406    1.43134488445726    1.43134488455672    1.43134488479412    1.43134488511417    1.43134488513491    1.43134488515487    1.43134488549475    1.43134488551493    1.43134488575256    1.43134488577429    1.43134488585639    1.43134488595408    1.43134488607300    1.43134488617274    1.43134488627238    1.43134488637234    1.43134488647368    1.43134488657538    1.43134488667679    1.43134488677362    1.43134488687361    1.43134488697368    1.43134488707580    1.43134488717212    1.43134488727594    1.43134488737356    1.43134488747503    1.43134488757348    1.43134488767390    1.43134488777366    1.43134488787348    1.43134488797220    1.43134488807357    1.43134488817360    1.43134488827645    1.43134488837374    1.43134488847267    1.43134488857295    1.43134488867220    1.43134488877195    1.43134488887405    1.43134488897557    1.43134488907217    1.43134488917212    1.43134488927209    1.43134488937227    1.43134488947417    1.43134488957420    1.43134488967209    1.43134488977399    1.43134488987214    1.43134488997216    1.43134489007218    1.43134489017214    1.43134489027231    1.43134489037207    1.43134489049212    1.43134489057214    1.43134489069366    1.43134489077184    1.43134489087193    1.43134489099201    1.43134489109194    1.43134489119202    1.43134489129195    1.43134489139200    1.43134489149218    1.43134489159365    1.43134489169239    1.43134489179276    1.43134489189365    1.43134489199413    1.43134489209293    1.43134489219382    1.43134489229786    1.43134489239448    1.43134489249426    1.43134489259670    1.43134489269287    1.43134489279240    1.43134489289328    1.43134489299374    1.43134489309232    1.43134489319400    1.43134489329388    1.43134489339827    1.43134489349972    1.43134489360104    1.43134489369289    1.43134489379317    1.43134489389273    1.43134489399286    1.43134489409324    1.43134489419312    1.43134489429313    1.43134489439631    1.43134489449326    1.43134489459336    1.43134489469317    1.43134489479317    1.43134489489348    1.43134489501583    1.43134489509336    1.43134489519904    1.43134489531375    1.43134489541655    1.43134489551347    1.43134489561351    1.43134489571300    1.43134489581306    1.43134489591337    1.43134489601324    1.43134489611328    1.43134489621609    1.43134489631330    1.43134489641341    1.43134489651327    1.43134489661529    1.43134489671340    1.43134489681340    1.43134489691342    1.43134489701640    1.43134489711667    1.43134489722016    1.43134489731369    1.43134489741375    1.43134489751387    1.43134489761383    1.43134489771369    1.43134489781693    1.43134489791857    1.43134489801410    1.43134489823443    1.43134489831406    1.43134489841449    1.43134489851784    1.43134489862065    1.43134489871979    1.43134489882194    1.43134489892139    1.43134489902343    1.43134489911814    1.43134489921789    1.43134489931751    1.43134489941911    1.43134489952363    1.43134489961810    1.43134489972013    1.43134489981939    1.43134489993967    1.43134490003661    1.43134490013926    1.43134490023765    1.43134490033767    1.43134490044096    1.43134490053922    1.43134490063994    1.43134490074100    1.43134490083606    1.43134490093878    1.43134490104843    1.43134490113590    1.43134490123840    1.43134490134073    1.43134490143578    1.43134490153882    1.43134490163754    1.43134490173662    1.43134490183932    1.43134490194108    1.43134490204059    1.43134490213864    1.43134490223860    1.43134490233795    1.43134490244263    1.43134490254084    1.43134490264354    1.43134490274155    1.43134490284570    1.43134490294231    1.43134490304075    1.43134490314132    1.43134490324588    1.43134490333993    1.43134490344199    1.43134490354365    1.43134490364113    1.43134490374087    1.43134490383849    1.43134490393825    1.43134490404238    1.43134490414231    1.43134490423683    1.43134490433711    1.43134490443707    1.43134490454241    1.43134490463800    1.43134490476108    1.43134490486269    1.43134490495979    1.43134490506325    1.43134490516266    1.43134490526285    1.43134490535759    1.43134490546094    1.43134490556078    1.43134490565740    1.43134490576174    1.43134490586053    1.43134490595848    1.43134490605953    1.43134490615725    1.43134490626256    1.43134490636420    1.43134490646213    1.43134490656237    1.43134490666564    1.43134490675812    1.43134490686632    1.43134490695776    1.43134490705788    1.43134490715787    1.43134490726016    1.43134490735832    1.43134490745778    1.43134490756385    1.43134490765771    1.43134490775915    1.43134490786502    1.43134490796298    1.43134490806277    1.43134490815729    1.43134490825732    1.43134490836770    1.43134490846235    1.43134490856242    1.43134490866799    1.43134490876612    1.43134490886517    1.43134490896335    1.43134490906446    1.43134490918268    1.43134490926698    1.43134490938207    1.43134490947830    1.43134490957965    1.43134490967977    1.43134490978564    1.43134490988427    1.43134490998250    1.43134491008444    1.43134491027830    1.43134491040209    1.43134491047945    1.43134491057726    1.43134491068054    1.43134491077754    1.43134491088069    1.43134491097698    1.43134491107920    1.43134491118098    1.43134491128398    1.43134491138521    1.43134491147783    1.43134491158736    1.43134491168111    1.43134491178022    1.43134491187874    1.43134491198209    1.43134491208459    1.43134491218077    1.43134491228186    1.43134491242085    1.43134491248290    1.43134491258096    1.43134491268100    1.43134491278144    1.43134491287854    1.43134491298102    1.43134491308044    1.43134491317801    1.43134491330101    1.43134491338228    1.43134491348084    1.43134491357880    1.43134491367504    1.43134491377597    1.43134491387936    1.43134491397945    1.43134491407589    1.43134491417503    1.43134491427849    1.43134491437575    1.43134491449874    1.43134491459858    1.43134491469459    1.43134491479845    1.43134491489875    1.43134491499527    1.43134491509476    1.43134491519451    1.43134491529460    1.43134491539452    1.43134491549823    1.43134491559851    1.43134491569782    1.43134491579436    1.43134491589408    1.43134491599410    1.43134491609538    1.43134491619407    1.43134491629527    1.43134491639455    1.43134491649542    1.43134491659813    1.43134491670053    1.43134491679437    1.43134491689410    1.43134491699513    1.43134491709744    1.43134491719402    1.43134491729772    1.43134491739689    1.43134491749644    1.43134491759824    1.43134491769367    1.43134491779665    1.43134491789599    1.43134491799673    1.43134491811371    1.43134491819365    1.43134491829686    1.43134491839660    1.43134491849369    1.43134491859349    1.43134491871363    1.43134491881355    1.43134491889339    1.43134491901727    1.43134491911657    1.43134491921414    1.43134491931400    1.43134491941704    1.43134491952140    1.43134491961854    1.43134491971383    1.43134491981663    1.43134491991657    1.43134492001669    1.43134492011367    1.43134492021368    1.43134492031354    1.43134492041360    1.43134492051368    1.43134492061678    1.43134492071376    1.43134492081368    1.43134492091603    1.43134492101411    1.43134492111585    1.43134492121545    1.43134492131744    1.43134492141939    1.43134492151792    1.43134492161974    1.43134492171807    1.43134492181814    1.43134492192011    1.43134492202062    1.43134492211350    1.43134492221270    1.43134492231379    1.43134492241180    1.43134492251475    1.43134492261076
```

Comment: Your `timeinepoch` values are all about 1 second. Are you sure you are not missing and exponent part? Also, include and example with input and desired output

Comment: @LuisMendo I added all the data I have for one array.. The expected output  are range of seconds from 0 to 100 almost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% vector of epoch times... (this is one of the values you posted)
epoch = 1.431344867477355;

% something is funky with your times, they are scaled
%   by a factor of 1e9, so we'll fix that here
epoch = epoch * 1e9;

% epoch time -> MATLAB datenum
dnum = datenum(1970,1,1,0,0,epoch);

% split time into parts
[Y, M, D, H, MN, S] = datevec(dnum);

% S is the seconds
```

The output is:

```
Y =

        2015


M =

     5


D =

    11


H =

    11


MN =

    47


S =

   47.4774
```

Comment: All the seconds for all the data above I gave are 1.4313 .. @siliconwafer

Comment: You are right the data I provided are divided by 1e9.. and It work if I applied your code for each element alone not as an array.. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

This command gives you the milliseconds since epoch(1-Jan-1970) in matlab.

```
>> int64(milliseconds(datetime('now','Timezone','UTC')-datetime('1970-01-01','Timezone','UTC')))
```

I verified it using https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)